# Adding tensors rows to a tensor given possibly repeating row indices

Tags: python, pytorch

In PyTorch, is there a batch version of the following (in-place) operations?

```
# v is a tensor of shape (n, m)
# w is a tensor of shape (k, m)
# indices is a tensor of shape (k, )

def f_sum(v, w, indices):
   for i, w0 in zip(indices, w):
      v[i] += w0

def f_average(v, w, indices):
   for i, w0 in zip(indices, w):
      v[i] += (1 / sum(indices == i)) * w0
```

Maybe, I think (?), the first operation is equivalent to `v[indices] += w` when it is guaranteed that `indices` does not have repititions, but we don't assume that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage these operations with the built-in [`scatter_add_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_add_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_add_). For the scatter average operation (`f_average`), you can either use `scatter_add` twice or a 3rd party library such as [PyTorch scatter](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_scatter) which offers such operation out of the box.

If you look at the documentation for that function, we are looking to do:

```
v[i][index[i][j]] += w[i][j]
```

Therefore we first need to make sure the `index` tensor has the same number of dimensions as the input you are scattering towards:

```
index = indices[:,None].expand_as(w)
```

- **Scatter add**

  By applying the **in-place** function `scatter_add_`:

  ```
  v.scatter_add_(dim=0, index=index, src=w)
  ```
- **Scatter mean**

  You can get the mean by scattering a tensor full of ones and diving `v` by it:

  ```
  v /= torch.zeros_like(v).scatter_add(dim=0, index=index, src=torch.ones_like(w))
  ```